# How to cache file editing history in Vim, that it would not disappear after switching the file?

Tags: undo-redo, persistent-state, command-history

When I open another file in a Vim session all editing history for the other files disappears.

Is it possible to configure Vim that it would automatically save and restore file editing history when hopping through files?

Comment: `gvim` and `vim` are the same program. Just the UI is different.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes you are right, I'll update the question.

Comment: Voted to reopen because, as I read the question, the OP isn’t closing Vim, merely switching files within it. `’undofile’` isn’t required to fix this: setting `'hidden'` will suffice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I do is add the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/undo/
```

That way all your undo/change tree information is saved across vim sessions, and next time you open your file you can still undo/redo old edits.

Comment: You also need to `mkdir ~/.vim/undo`. Vim won't autocreate it.